# Power BI - x axis skips year

Tags: powerbi

The chart has data from 2009 to 2023. The tooltip shows value from 2009 to 2023. But the label in the x-axis shows only the even number years (2010 to 2022).

I do not prefer changing the x axis to categorical as it will show all the data from 2009 to 2023 and it will have a scroll bar.

[image]

When I enlarge the visual, it shows 2024, but not 2023. It has data till 2023. The tooltip also shows the data but the axis is not showing the year.

So far I have tried the following:

1. reducing the font size.
2. changing the maximum value in x axis.
3. enlarging the visual.

However, the issue is not solved.

Comment: Convert your chart into a table and check first, you have date for 2009 and 2023 or not.

Comment: You did not say what data you actually want to show. You don't want future dates to show, and you want some individual years to show but apparently not all since showing back to 2009 creates a scroll bar. What exactly do you want to show, and what is stopping you from just filtering to that and changing the X-axis to categorical?

Comment: This chart will be exported as PDF. So I need to show all the data from 2009 to 2023. I am looking for a solution, where the line chart shows all the data and X axis labels show 2009, 2011,2013,2015,2017,2019,2021 , 2023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the options available to you with native visuals have been tried. If you choose continuous, then PBI will decide what labels to show. If you use categorical, then you'll see every label.

If you want finer control over ticks and axis labels, you need to use a non-native visual. I can recommend Deneb which will give you the level of control you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the font size small and i hope it works.

Comment: Yes It has data till 2023. The tooltip also shows the data but the axis is not showing the year